# Why does Java Swing draw at the wrong place?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

To be more specific I edit the question by replacing it with some reproducible code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class TestStackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestStackOverflow();
    }
    
    public TestStackOverflow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {


                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel header = new JPanel();
                header.add(new JLabel("Hello, I'm the header"));
                header.setBackground(Color.red);
                
                window.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                window.add(new TestPane());
                
         
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        
        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
        
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            g.drawRect(900, 0, 100, 100);
            
            //System.out.println(getWidth());       
        
        }
    }

}
```

This code shows the rectangle being drawn too far right. I saw with "getWidth" that the width is actually less then 1000, but I had defined with window.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000)) the size of the window. So, why is it just 984 instead of 1000. The swing documentation says that the component would take the remaining space and that would / should be in my case 1000.

[image of wrong placed rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxebF.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: The size of the panel is NOT the size of the frame. The frame contains a title bar and borders. Your painting should be relative to the size of the panel which means you should not be hardcoding values, but instead use the getWidth()/getHeight() values of the panel to control your painting. Also don't call your class "Window". The is an AWT component with that name so it is confusing. Class names should be more descriptive.

Comment: @camickr I learned that the panel would draw things based on itself and not surroundings so that when I set the panels size to 1000*1000 and draw at 900 / 0 there should be a drawing?!

Comment: @kleopatra I edited my code to be reproducable!

Comment: Its edited! Please have a look!

Comment: What do you think is wrong exactly - it's not clear?

Comment: @g00se That the rectangle is placed not in the corner because the window is slightly smaler then 1000*1000 and I don't understand why...

Comment: It's certainly in the corner when I run it. Perhaps you should post a screenshot

Comment: I added the image!

Comment: *the window is slightly smaler then 1000x1000 and I don't understand why* - The window is not smaller than 1000. The panel is smaller than 1000 and the reason has already been given. *so that when I set the panels size to ...* - you are NOT setting the panels size, you are setting the size of the window which contains the decorations AND the panel. If you want the panel to be 1000, then you need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel and then `pack()` the frame after adding the panel to the frame. Don't use setSize(). Let the layout managers determine the size of the window.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want it in the corner of the whole window. In that case you need to override the frame's painting method. Demo obviously - I'm not suggesting you write it exactly like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestStackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestStackOverflow();
    }

    public TestStackOverflow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                JFrame window = new JFrame() {
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics g) {
                        super.paint(g);

                        g.drawRect(900, 0, 100, 100);

                        // System.out.println(getWidth());

                    }
                };
                window.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel header = new JPanel();
                header.add(new JLabel("Hello, I'm the header"));
                header.setBackground(Color.red);

                window.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                window.add(new TestPane());

                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.blue);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            //g.drawRect(900, 0, 100, 100);

            // System.out.println(getWidth());

        }
    }

}
```